# Let $f\colon V \rightarrow W$ and $A$ be the matrix of $f$ for a certain bases, find $\dim(V), \dim(W), \dim(\text{null}(f))$ and $\dim(\text{im}(f))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f\colon V \rightarrow W$ and A be the matrix of $f$ for certain bases, find $\dim(V), \dim(W), \dim(\text{null}(f))$ and $\dim(\text{im}(f))$. $A$ is given by the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 &  8 & 9 \\
10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
\end{bmatrix}

The rank of the matrix is $2$. Using the fact that $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(f)$ and $\text{rank(f)}$ being defined as $\dim(\text{im}(f))$, it follows that $\dim(\text{im}(f))=2$.

Now I'm not sure about about the dimension of $V$ and $W$. Would I necessarily need to find a basis of $V$ to show that $V$ has a certain dimension or could I simply use the fact that any $x$ that is inserted into $f$ has to have 5 elements and therefore $V$ also has dimension $5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to find a basis to determine the dimensions. Since the matrix $A$ is a map $\mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^4$ the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are $5$ and $4$, respectively.

Assuming that the rank of the matrix is $2$ you may then apply the rank nullity theorem to determine the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: It needn't be from $\mathbb R^5$ to $\mathbb R^4$ at all.

Comment: Yes, I'd assume that the matrix would also work e.g. with vector spaces of polynomials. But does that matter when determining the dimensions of V and W?

Comment: @eager2learn It doesn't matter at all, restricting to $\mathbb R^5$ and $\mathbb R^4$ isn't necessary to make the answer correct.

Comment: @eager2learn See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Dimension_Characterizes_Isomorphism) for why I can write $\mathbb R^n$ above.